# rel="dns-prefetch" / rel="preconnect" vs far-future expiry headers...?

Tags: cache, expires, rel-dns-prefetch

I've always been a big fan of far-futures expiry headers.  First time visit on my site's homepage results in 40 HTTP requests, but a subsequent visit comes in at 1, with a response as snappy as you'd expect.  This is great, very happy.

I've just learnt about dns-prefetch and preconnect though.  I can see that they'd help (marginally) with a first-time load, but I assume the extra overhead is a bad thing on subsequent loads, since I'd be initiating some DNS lookups/SSL handshakes for domains which then don't even get used.

What's the best practice, or how have you tackled this?